# Ireland student visa financial requirements for funded offer

Tags: student-visa, study, ireland

I recently received offer from TU Dublin for funded PhD ( fee + maintenance ). I was going through financial requirements for student visa application for [non-EEA students](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Notice%20Regarding%20Evidence%20of%20Finances%20for%20all%20Non%20EEA%20Students). It is bit unclear on how much money we have to show. In website its written as

> Scholarship Students
>
> In addition students in receipt of a scholarship which either part funds or fully funds both their course fees and living costs must provide a letter, issued to them by the relevant organisation confirming they are the recipient of a scholarship.

Can some one please clarify what's above sentence means ? Does it mean they are considering Scholarship students as another category like visa required and not required students ? Or scholarship students have to show 7000£ + letter specifying they have scholarship ?

Thanks.

Comment: The sentence does not mention a sum of money. Where does the 7,000 figure come from?

Comment: Questions about long term migration, including student visas, belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: @Richard Beasley It’s in the link in the OP’s question: “students from Visa required countries are required to demonstrate that they have access to €7,000 as part of their Visa application”

Comment: @RichardBeasley Please ref [this](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Notice%20Regarding%20Evidence%20of%20Finances%20for%20all%20Non%20EEA%20Students)  and £7000 is mentioned for students from Visa required countries

Comment: The link mentions € 7000, not £ 7000. The official currency in the Republic of Ireland is the Euro, not the Pound.

Answer (score 1):

This text says nothing about another class of visa.

It says only that if an applicant for a student visa has or will receive a scholarship for partial or full support of their studies and/or living expenses, then the applicant must provide (to the Irish immigration authorities, as part of their visa application) a letter from the "relevant organization," i.e., the college or university, confirming the scholarship.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it starts with "In addition" , So does it mean visa required student has to provide financial evidence of £7000 ( Please ref link in question ) and scholarship letter ? ( Its  not clear from the given description)

Comment: The page linked in your question says non-EEA students from visa-required countries undertaking a course of study in Ireland must show access to €7,000. I think that applies to you, and you must demonstrate that the funds available to you (cash or available accounts combined with the amount awarded in the scholarship letter) total €7,000. I would, however, ask TU Dublin at their financial air or international student office; they will surely have addressed this issue before.